# How can I get the Autonomous System Number (ASN) and Netblock Owner for an IP in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I need to look up the ASN and Netblock owner for a specific IP in a .NET server app.

Is this info in the WhoIs data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Team Cymru has an [IP address to ASN mapping service](https://team-cymru.com/community-services/ip-asn-mapping/).  Please be sure to follow their terms of service, though...

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. I currently have a request in with them to see if I can use their service.

Comment: This is my script, I mean.. it is free..  https://github.com/jamesjara/netblock-backbone/blob/master/netblock_prescanner.php just download the database files.